# What is the meaning of this conversation?

Tags: expressions, conversation

This is from an anime called Yu Yu Hakusho.

The girl is looking for something to drink.

- Girl: O.J.? It's better for you than a soda.
- Boy: That's fine, just pour it over ice and we can share with each
  other as long as we use two straws.
- Girl: Your confidence in my health is charming.

I don't understand what she means by "Your confidence in my health is charming."  What is she trying to say?

[image]

Comment: She's being ***ironic*** - referencing the fact that the boy seeks to avoid catching her hypothetical oral herpes if they use a shared straw or both drink direct from the same glass (i.e. - he has ***no*** faith that she's healthy).

Answer (score 1):

The boy asks for two straws, possibly because he thinks sharing a straw is demanding an intimacy that is premature.

The girl, possibly trying to keep the boy off balance, implies that the boy fears that she has some worrisome disease.

Fortunately, once you are past about 80, this kind of sexual complexity dissipates.